# Kivy app crashing on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wrote a simple app using kivy. It works just fine on my desktop, but i want it to run on Android. However, when i install it to my Android phone, it crashes on startup.

The app broadcasts on the lan, waiting for a reply. Then whoever replies is added to a list and displayed on the screen.

this is my code:

```
import kivy
import random
import socket
import threading

kivy.require('1.7.2')  # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from functools import partial

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
import socket
import random

CHECK_MESSAGE = "Who is alive?"


class Communicator:

    def requester(self):
        address = ('<broadcast>', 54545)

        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

        string_list =[]

        while True:
            #print "broadcasting done by " + self.my_name
            client_socket.sendto(CHECK_MESSAGE, address)
            recv_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048)

            if self.my_name == recv_data or recv_data in string_list:
                sleep(3)
                continue

            string_list.append(recv_data)
            self.callback(string_list)
            sleep(3)

    def replyer(self):
        address = ('', 54545)
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        server_socket.bind(address)
        #print my_name

        while True:
            #print "Listening"
            recv_data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)
            if recv_data == CHECK_MESSAGE:
                server_socket.sendto(self.my_name, addr)

    def __init__(self, callback_function):
        self.callback = callback_function
        self.my_name = socket.gethostname() + ' ' + str(int(random.random()*10000))

    def start_all(self):
        self.start_server()
        self.start_client()

    def start_client(self):
        client = threading.Thread(target=self.requester)
        client.daemon = True
        client.start()

    def start_server(self):
        server = threading.Thread(target=self.replyer)
        server.daemon = True
        server.start()

class Client:
    name = ''

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

client_list =[]



class Pong(Screen):
    grid_l = ObjectProperty(None)
    top_lbl = ObjectProperty(None)
    list_of_peers = ObjectProperty(None)

    def search_btn_pressed(self, string_list):
        #if self.queue.qsize() > 0:

        #print "sieze:" , self.queue.qsize()
        grid = self.grid_l
        grid.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'),
                  minimum_width=grid.setter('width'))

        x = random.randint(2, 5)

        #if self.list_of_peers is not None:
        #    grid.remove_widget(self.list_of_peers)
        self.grid_l.clear_widgets()

        self.list_of_peers = GridLayout(cols=1, row_default_height=40,
                                        row_force_default=False)
        self.list_of_peers.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'),
                                minimum_width=grid.setter('width'))
        print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()))
        for i in string_list:
                btn1 = Button(size_hint=(1, None))
                btn1.text = str(i)
                #btn1.bind(on_release=partial(self.btn1_pressed, result))
                self.list_of_peers.add_widget(btn1)

        grid.add_widget(self.list_of_peers)

    def btn1_pressed(self, result, *args):
        new_text = result
        self.top_lbl.text = new_text

    def btn2_pressed(self, *args):
        self.grid_l.clear_widgets()
        #pass


class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):

        my_app = Pong()
        queue = Queue()

        my_app.queue = queue
        Communicator(my_app.search_btn_pressed).start_all()

        return my_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = PongApp().run()
```

and pong.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.7.2

<Pong>:
    scroll_view: scrollviewID
    top_lbl: lblID
    grid_l: gridlayoutID
    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .9}
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Label:
            id: lblID
            text: 'This is the app..'
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .8}
        text: 'Refresh?'
        #on_release: root.search_btn_pressed()

    ScrollView:
        id: scrollviewID
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1, .8
        bar_width: '8dp'
        GridLayout:
            id: gridlayoutID
            cols: 1
            size_hint: 1, None
            row_default_height: 40
            row_force_default: False
```

i ran " ./distribute.sh -m "openssl pil kivy" " 
and then
"./build.py --dir ~/Desktop/MyProject/ --package org.test.florin --name
 "ShareAll" --version 0.0.1 --permission INTERNET debug installd  "

This gets the app to my phone, but when i start it up, it crashes. 
Am i missing something? Dont know how to get to any errors..

It's my first time with kivy (or Android for that matter)

This is the adb logcat
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=28KaFM79

dont know why it's that big..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I/python  (16193): No main.pyo / main.py found.

This is the error in your file (you can see the kivy-related lines by grepping `python` or using adb's own syntax for this).

So...is your main file called main.py? If so, it's not getting included for some reason.

Comment: I only have 1 file(that's the main file), called PongApp.py (I started from the tutorial on the website, and went with the same file). In order for it to work on Android i need to rename it to 'main.py'? (tried it just now, it didnt work)

Comment: Yes, the main runnable file must be called main.py. If it doesn't work, post a new adb log.

Comment: From what i can tell, it's complaining that it cannot find 'multiprocessing' : "I/python  (27549):  ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing.           Full log: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=DQgBFqUp .  Do i need to manually import the libraries that i am using, or mention them somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I don't think it's possible to use multiprocessing on android, so we blacklist it and don't even include the module to save a little space. You're limited to to threads or an android service instead. (Edit: I asked on irc and it seems maybe other things could *maybe* work, but I don't know the details - I suggest asking on the irc or mailing list yourself).

Comment: So how do i know what python libraries i can use?

Comment: Yey, it worked :D Removing 'multiprocessing' did the trick (it was only there because i used it before, didnt really need it). Thank you very much for the help!